# Smartphone Android with integrated barcode scanner

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have developed an android application which uses camera for barcode reading. But this method seems to be pretty slow. So I would buy a Smartphone with integrated barcode scanner.

This is an [example](http://swiftautoid.en.alibaba.com/product/1347715484-210847454/Smartphone_Scanner_Enterprise_Sled_with_Samsung_Android_Smartphone_1D_2D_RFID_GS_SL2000_Barcode_scanner.html?edm_src=sys&edm_type=fdbk&edm_grp=0&edm_cta=read_msg&edm_time=realtime&edm_ver=e) GS-SL2100 Android Smartphone Scanner

but I'm not sure, if i buy this product, how do i connect of the barcode scanner? Have you any idea? Some suggestion?

Comment: Could you please define what slow means in seconds or milliseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently developing an app with an integrated barcode scanner making use of Sean Owen's 'ZXing'.

I am not entirely clear as to what you mean by the method being pretty slow. ZXing is generally blazing fast for me, sometimes decoding before the screen has finished loading. I have experienced however, that the scanner sometimes took a long time to scan and kept refocusing. I discovered it was because there were other small example barcodes nearby which was confusing it.

If this is indeed what you meant by it being slow, try scanning a barcode without any other barcodes in view.

Comment: I am using the S7710 Samsung Xcover 2.

Answer (score 1):

Motorola Solutions is developing android-based devices that have a standard (laser-based or imager) bar code scanner. If you are doing a lot of scanning this is what you are going to want to use. Take a look at the MC67.